# Matching more than one segment

Tags: conditionals, segments, advanced-conditionals

Matching one URL segments always works fine but is possible to match more than one?

For example this works:

```
{if segment_2 == "page"}nav-expanded nav-active{/if}
```

But this does not:

```
{if segment_2 == "page1" OR "page2"}nav-expanded nav-active{/if}
```

I tried all operators and conditionals possible and nothing works for me from the official docs here:
**https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/conditionals.htm**

I need to match more than one page (not at the same time) but no operators I test like *equal*, *or*, *and* seems to work with *segments*. I'm trying to avoid having to create a whole new **{if segment_2}** for every single sub-menu page

Maybe this is not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use this to check multiple pages:

```
{if "page1|page2" *= segment_2} active {/if}
```

Comment: While the other solutions also work, this is the correct answer. I don't want to keep adding segment_2 for each page, but just once and specify the pages to match. Your code is the clean short solution to this. Thank you!

Comment: You are most welcome. This is actually contains key `*=`

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code.

```
{if segment_2 == "page1" || segment_2 == "page2"} nav-expanded nav-active {/if}
```

I hope this will works for you.

Comment: I tried this before posting here. || is basically the same operator as OR, I think I don't use segment_2 twice but I will test this again.

Comment: You can use `segment_2` twice in `if` condition, there is no problem with that. I am sure this will definitely works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{if segment_2 == "page1" OR  segment_2 == "page2" }nav-expanded nav-active{/if}
```